# Open Source Contributor License Agreements / Apache2 and patents

Tags: licensing, patents, open-source-software

Many CLAs contain the below clause that is more or less taken from the Apache2 license:

> Grant of Patent License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this
>   Agreement, You hereby grant to ACME and to recipients of software
>   distributed by ACME a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge,
>   royalty-free, irrevocable (except as stated in this section) patent
>   license to make, have made, use, offer to sell, sell, import, and
>   otherwise transfer the Work, where such license applies only to those
>   patent claims licensable by You that are necessarily infringed by Your
>   Contribution(s) alone or by combination of Your Contribution(s) with
>   the Work to which such Contribution(s) was submitted. If any entity
>   institutes patent litigation against You or any other entity
>   (including a cross-claim or counterclaim in a lawsuit) alleging that
>   your Contribution, or the Work to which you have contributed,
>   constitutes direct or contributory patent infringement, then any
>   patent licenses granted to that entity under this Agreement for that
>   Contribution or Work shall terminate as of the date such litigation is
>   filed.

I am unsure about what this means in a scenario where

1. A project we contribute to does infringe some patent of my company
2. My contribution does not contain or touch those code parts

If I read this correctly

> [...] that are necessarily infringed by Your
>   Contribution(s) alone or by combination of Your Contribution(s) with
>   the Work to which such Contribution(s) was submitted [...]

my contribution has to infringe that patent and if it does I grant the license. So the question is - when is a patent considered to be infringed?
If I just change a typo?

Our lawyers take is:

- if we sign the CLA
- and contribute to a project that infringes one of our patents in *any way*
- we will grant the license

Consequently, we have to check each project we contribute to for potential patent violations. (which is pretty much impossible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of these patent clauses is two-fold:

- that contributors cannot create patent traps. For example: contributor A makes contributions. Using the contributions causes A's patents to be infringed. Without these clauses, A could later sue the project's users.
- that someone who works against the project by claiming patent infringement doesn't simultaneously enjoy other contributor's patent licenses: you can't sue *and* use the project. This is intended to discourage legal action against the project and its users.

Normally, a patent-relevant contribution would work like this:

- the project is not infringing your patents
- you make a contribution
- with this contribution, the project would infringe your patents
- by making the contribution, you issue a license to these patents

You are suggesting a more interesting scenario:

- the project is infringing your patents
- you make a contribution that does not relate to the infringed patents

Will this contribution then cause a patent license to be issued?

- Whether or not you grant a license, you can't sue for infringement or any patent licenses you received through the project will terminate.
- “Combination” can denote an act or a state/result.
- The act of combining of your contribution with the project doesn't cause your patents to be infringed. However, the result of the combination does infringe the patents.
- I could see this being argued either way.
- As a patent holder, the safe assumption would be that you would be issuing a license for any patents that would be infringed by the result of the combination of your contributions with the project.
- Your lawyer's advice seems sensible.

You are not required to check the project for possible violations first: you do not need to explicitly license individual patents, you effectively just lose the right to claim infringement.

If you are a patent holder and do not want to freely license these patents, then you should stay away from such CLAs and open source projects in general.

- Do not contribute to such projects. Do not copy or share such projects.
- If you need to modify the project, keep the modifications private.
- If you want to use such software, prepare a migration plan to a different software in case you want to claim that the project is infringing your patents.
- Note that there's a legal theory that open source licenses without an explicit patent license (like MIT, BSD) may still have an *implied* patent license, either through the rights that you grant or through estoppel.